# My spy function is not getting called - how can I properly spy this function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, spy

I'm trying to do call a function that is imported as a function independently in another function that I'm calling from my unit test.  How can I get callcount of 1 on the functionIWantToSpy in this scenario?

auditEvent.js:

```
const { verify } = require('@mycompany/verifylib');
const { functionIWantToSpy } = require('@mycompany/another-lib');

const auditEvent = () => {
  verify();
  functionIWantToSpy();
};

module.exports = { auditEvent };
```

test:

```
const { verify } = require('@mycompany/verify-lib');
const { functionIWantToSpy } = require('@mycompany/another-lib');

describe('mytest', () => {

  let spiedFuntion;
  let verifyStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    verifyStub = sinon.stub();
    ({auditEvent} = proxyquire('./auditEvent', {
      '@mycompny/verify-lib': {
        verify: verifyStub,
        '@noCallThru': true,
      },
    }));
    spiedFunction = sinon.spy(functionIWantToSpy);
  });

  it('should work'), async () => {

    auditEvent();
    expect(functionIWantToSpy).to.have.callCount(1);   // Getting callcount of 0 here...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spying involves replacing the function with a new function. You are replacing what is referred to by the identifier `functionIWantToSpy` so that it refers to a new spy function, instead of the original function referred to by `require('@mycompany/another-lib').functionIWantToSpy`. The code inside the module can't see your new spy function. The expression `require('@mycompany/another-lib').functionIWantToSpy` refers to the original function, unchanged.

Because [`require` caches results](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/201212/51295) (i.e., only the first `require("foo")` executes `foo`, and any subsequent `require("foo")` summons up that same object returned by the first `require` call), you can modify the `functionIWantToSpy` method of the `require('@mycompany/another-lib')` object, using the two-argument form of `sinon.spy`:

```
spiedFunction = sinon.spy(require('@mycompany/another-lib'), "functionIWantToSpy");
```

You *must* do this *before* the property is ever accessed (and value stored) by the module being tested:

```
verifyStub = sinon.stub();

// IMPORANT: FIRST, spy the functionIWantToSpy property on the required object before importing auditEvent
spiedFunction = sinon.spy(require('@mycompany/another-lib'), "functionIWantToSpy");

({auditEvent} = proxyquire('./auditEvent', {
  '@mycompny/verify-lib': {
    verify: verifyStub,
    '@noCallThru': true,
  },
}));
```

This should work because when the auditEvent module runs for the first time and gets to

```
const { functionIWantToSpy } = require('@mycompany/another-lib');
```

then `require('@mycompany/another-lib').functionIWantToSpy` will refer to the spy function.

Comment: So perfectly explained - thank you very much!